# Is Menu-minipanels reliable to make a mega menu

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I'm going to implement a mega menu in my site and am considering the [Menu Minipanels](http://drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels) module...

Has anyone tried it? Did you find it easy to use/customize?

What about performance? Panels is often quite a heavy module.

Answer (score 1):

[Menu Minipanels](http://drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels) looks like a good choice.

An alternative you might want to try for a simple 'mega menu' is the [Mega Menus module](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu). Worked well for me, once I had my settings and CSS sorted out. See also [this answer for lots more mega menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15285/4543) options...

Finally, regarding performance, since Menu Minipanels uses Panels you will have full control over caching of individual panes within it. The performance burden can therefore be significantly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new mega menu module called [TB Mega Menu](http://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) which I found pretty helpful and extremely easy to use. Its got a friendly user interface (WYSIWYG) along with some nice features such as synchronized with Drupal core menu, nice design, built on Twitter Bootstrap, responsive...